# I want to have contour lines passing through the triangle. How to do it using THREE.js

Tags: three.js, shader

[image]

Let's say I have 4 vertices and I don't want default interpolation but something of this sort. I have the color data. How should I achieve this using THREE.js?

Comment: What does your color data look like? This seems like a candidate for texturing. I doubt that you can control a shape like this by using vertex interpolation, at least not with 4 vertices.

Comment: You have three options: 1) Apply the contours as a texture, 2) A shader which can calculate your contours and replace the fragment color correctly, 3) Model the contours and place them coplanar to your surface, then use geometry offsets to "push" the plane behind the contours during rendering. All that said, we'll need more than this to help you. Please share any code you have, and indicate what you've already tried to achieve your desired effect.

Comment: Thank you @pailhead, TheJim01. I think I am looking for  "2) A shader which can calculate your contours and replace the fragment color correctly". I have not written shader yet. I was using the default interpolation based on vertex colors which obviously cannot produce such effect.
I will look further into shaders. I appreciate your help. It would be nice if you could suggest a good online material/ book on this subject.